# How can I bind different keys to buttons in Python? (Basic Calculator)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button, calculator, bind

I am new in programming and I started doing a calculator, I want to each button to be interactive for Numpad keys (when you press 8, for example, the calculator screen shows it)

Here is the code I've done:

```
def clear():

      global operador

      operador = ""

      texto_pantalla.set("0")

#functions


def click(b):

    global operador

    operador += str(b)

    texto_pantalla.set(operador)

def resultado():

    global operador

    try:
        r = str(eval(operador))
    except:
        r = "ERROR"
    texto_pantalla.set(r)

#Row 1
    
       Boton7 = Button(ventana,text="7", font="System", bg=color_boton1, width=ancho_boton1, height=alto_boton1, fg=color_font_boton1, command=lambda:click(7)).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

       Boton8 = Button(ventana,text="8", font="System", bg=color_boton1, width=ancho_boton1, height=alto_boton1, fg=color_font_boton1, command=lambda:click(8)).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)

       Boton9 = Button(ventana,text="9", font="System", bg=color_boton1, width=ancho_boton1, height=alto_boton1, fg=color_font_boton1, command=lambda:click(9)).grid(row=1, column=2, pady=5)

       ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted far too much code, and you haven't formatted it correctly. If the question is about binding keys to buttons, we only need an example with a couple of buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry, I modified it. Do you know any solution?

Comment: This is not a complete example. Please read and follow the advice here: [mcve].